# How will I get the content ie the title of a tag while web scrapping with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am following this tutorial.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scrape-a-website-using-node-js-and-puppeteer

I am trying to learn how to use puppeteer.

I am trying to get whats written in the anchor tag .

So my code in pageScraper file is this

```
const scraperObject = {
    url: 'http://books.toscrape.com',
    async scraper(browser){
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}...`);
        // Navigate to the selected page
        await page.goto(this.url);
        // Wait for the required DOM to be rendered
        await page.waitForSelector('.page_inner');      

        let mytext=await page.$$eval('.nav-list li > a',text => text.textContent)
        
        console.log(mytext);
    }
}//         dataObj['bookTitle'] = await newPage.$eval('.product_main > h1', text => text.textContent);
module.exports = scraperObject;
```

However I am getting an undefined while printing.

I am trying to get this.
[Selectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GaoU.jpg)

[book text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6beo.png)

Comment: Okay, so then go into inspect element in your browser right click the element and get the selector link for it. Copy -> Copy selector should make guessing work easier for you for now. Just replace .page_inner with your new copied selector

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @LajosArpadma console.log its  printing undefined

Comment: @BGPHiJACK no I dont want to replace the .page_inner bc  I want to wait for it to become visible then proceed.However i tried doing the copy css selector thing but with the eval and its still showing undefined while logging

Answer (score 2):

First of all, http://books.toscrape.com doesn't have any functional JS, so there's no need for Puppeteer. Better to just use a lightweight static request library like fetch or axios and an HTML parser like Cheerio.

That said, for pedagogical purposes,

```js
await page.$$eval('.nav-list li > a',text => text.textContent)
```

appears to be the problem. [`$$eval`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.0.0/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) means "select all and run a callback on all selected elements in the browser context", similar to `document.querySelectorAll`. So the variable you call `text` is an array of elements, not a single element, and the array property `.textContent` is undefined.

If you want to select a single element, use [`$eval`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v14.0.0/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1). Please call the variable `element` or `el`, not `text`.

On the other hand, if you want to select multiple elements, treat it like an array in the callback.

Getting one element's text:

```js
await page.$eval('.nav-list li > a', el => el.textContent);
```

Getting multiple elements' text:

```js
await page.$$eval('.nav-list li > a', els => els.map(el => el.textContent));
```

Comment: It worked!! Btw if you dont mind can you upvote my post.Anyway thanks